# AngularJS $routeProvider.when() 's resolve route parameter - what is that 'key'?

Tags: angularjs

[AngulaR resolve API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)

The API says for resolve:

> key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.

@egghead, there is this video on the topic:

[egghead - Angular resolve](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve)

What i do not understand is what that key object is for and why the author of the above video does inject the controller into itself

Answer (score 2):

> key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the
>   controller.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        controller: 'ListCtrl',
        resolve: {
          myResolve: function(MyService) {
            return MyService();
          }
        },
        templateUrl:'./views/list.html'
  })
});
```

Instead of (in the controller)

```
app.controller('MyController',function($scope,MyService){
   $scope.data =  MyService();    
});
```

if you use resolve

```
app.controller('MyController',function($scope,myResolve){
    $scope.data =  myResolve;      
});
```

**UPDATE**

a working example

```
<!doctype html>
 <html ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content" data-ng-view=""></div>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
            myModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/', {
                        templateUrl: './index.html',
                        controller: 'IndexCtrl',
                        resolve: {
                            hello: function(Hello) {
                                return Hello.getMessages();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                });

            });
            myModule.factory('Hello', function($q, $timeout) {
                var getMessages = function() {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $timeout(function() {
                        deferred.resolve('Hello');

                    }, 1000);

                    return deferred.promise;
                };
                return {
                    getMessages: getMessages
                };
            });
            myModule.controller('IndexCtrl',function($scope,hello){
               $scope.hello =  hello;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the view

```
<p>{{hello}}</p>
```

Comment: Excuse me, but if i do so, i get `Error: Unknown provider: myResolveProvider <- myResolve`

Comment: post more code please (the service should return a promise in any case) and overall you should have the service :)